# View Many to Many Relationship in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

Product model code:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Category model code:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Product controller code:

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->get();
```

index.blade.php code:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <li>Product Name: {{$product->name}}</li>
    <li>Category: {{ $product->categories->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

When I use the above index.blade.php code the following error shows:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object.

Then I tried amending the index.blade.php code into the following:

```
<li>Category: {{ $product->categories }}</li>
```

And then I got the following as the output in my index.blade.php :

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Cameras"}]
```

May I know how I can show the name of the category related to specific product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`belongsToMany` or `hasMany` means this have many related models. laravel returns a collection instead of an object for these relationships. so you can't get a property directly like `$product->categories->name`, as categories is a collection here. you have to loop through the collection like

```
@foreach ($product->categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name }}
@endforeach
```

now you can access all the related categories to that product and get their properties.

Comment: glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
  <li>Product Name: {{$product->name}}</li>
    <ul>
      @foreach($product->categories as $category)
        <li>Category: {{ $category->name }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

`$product->categories` is a collection of related category records for the $product object not an object - hence the error

Answer (score 0):

As categories is a collection, you can iterate over it or benefit from laravel collection methods and **pluck** your desired property out of it.

By convertin the result of **pluck** method to array, you can implode them and show it as a string.  Below code may help you:

```
implode(', ', $product->categories->pluck('name')->toArray())
```